# VirtualBox: Windows Host, Ubuntu Guest, and guestcontrol

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox 4.2.4 on a Windows 7 host with a Ubuntu 12.04 guest.  In Windows, I would like to launch Firefox in Ubuntu using the [VBoxManage.exe guestcontrol](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) command.  However, it isn't quit working.  Below is the command and output:

```
C:\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe guestcontrol MyVirtualMachineUbuntu exec --image "/usr/bin/firefox" --user bob --password password --wait-stdout --verbose
Waiting for guest to start process ...
Waiting for process to exit ...
Exit code=1 (Status=500 [successfully terminated])
```

Nothing happens in the Ubuntu desktop.  I know the **/usr/bin/firefox** command works because it launches Firefox when I type it in the Ubuntu terminal.

I am able to run the /bin/ls examples in the documentation normally, so the basic functionality is working.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a wild quess, try running `xhost +` on the Ubuntu guest and trying the `VBoxManage.exe` command again.

Comment: @terdon thanks for the guess, but I tried 'xhost +' and there was no change.